# Change file extension in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, file-extension, document-library

I'm trying to find out how to change the file extension of a file in a document library in SharePoint, so that a newer version with a different extension can be uploaded without a separated copy being created (e.g. suppose I want to replace a .doc file with .zip).

Looks like you can write some codes to workaround but I feel there's gotta be a simpler way to do a simple task like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change the extension by opening the library in windows explorer.

Actions - Open In Windows Explorer

Then ensure that in your file view settings you don't have 'Hide Extensions for known file types' enabled.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I had thought SharePoint would not be able to find the file if I just change it in Windows Explorer - guess that's not the case :).